# Nonstandard-Analysis: Showing L'Hospital

Tags: derivatives, nonstandard-analysis

Let there be two functions $f,g:(a,b) \to\mathbb R$ that are differentiable in $(a,b)$ with either
$$\text{Case 1:}\qquad\lim_{x\to b} f(x) = \lim_{x\to b} g(x) = 0$$
or
$$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{Case 2:}\qquad\lim_{x\to b} f(x) = \lim_{x\to b} g(x) = \pm \infty$$

I want to show that $$\lim_{x\to b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to b} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$ if the right hand side of the equation exists.

My approach:
Since $f,g$ are differentiable, we have $f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+d)-f(x)}d$, where $d$ is an infinitesimal. 
Per algebraic transformations we can therefore deduce:
$$f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+d)-f(x)}d \\\Leftrightarrow\\
f'(x) +d_f =\frac{f(x+d)-f(x)}d \\\Leftrightarrow\\
f(x+d) = f(x) + df'(x) +dd_f
$$
(Which is a nice identity by itself)

From now on, let every variable of the form $d_x$ be an infinitesimal. We can deduce:
$$\lim_{x\to b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \approx\frac{f(b+d+d_2)}{g(b+d+d_2)} =\frac{f(b+d) + d_2f'(b+d) +d_2d_f}{g(b+d) + d_2g'(b+d) +d_2d_g} $$
(I've used $d+d_2$ rather than just $d$ because otherwise $f'(b)$ would be undefined)

Case 1: If the limit tends to $0$, we can simplify:
$$\frac{f(b+d) + d_2f'(b+d) +d_2d_f}{g(b+d) + d_2g'(b+d) +d_2d_g} = 
\frac{d_3 + d_2f'(b+d) +d_2d_f}{d_4 + d_2g'(b+d) +d_2d_g} $$

And here I'm stuck. $d_3$ and $d_4$ make it impossible to cancel out $d_2$.

Is there a way to make my reasoning whole?

Comment: @DarkKnight As a derivative is a limit process, the intuitive nonstandard-definition of the derivative is as I have given it (i.e. with $\approx$). However, I'm struggling to find a counterexample that clearly shows that $=$ can not be the case, so maybe this is a possible definition as well

Comment: @DarkKnight I found one after all: If $f'(x) = \dfrac{f(x+d)-f(x)}{d}$, then this means the equation holds for all infinitesimal $d$. Therefore, $$\dfrac{f(x+d)-f(x)}{d} = \dfrac{f(x+d_2)-f(x)}{d_2}$$. So, if we set $f(x) = x^2: $$$\dfrac{2xd+d^2}{d} = \dfrac{2xd_2+{d_2}^2}{d_2} \Leftrightarrow \frac{x^2}d - \frac{x^2}{d_2} = d-d_2$$ You arrive at a contradiction if you substitute x for any value and solve for $d$. You then see, that the equation only holds for '''some''' choices of $d,d_2$, not for '''all''.

Comment: I have deleted my comment. I am sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @DarkKnight It was nonetheless a nice suggestion that would have solved my problem if it had worked out

Comment: That's why I love to use the limit notation. What I thought was if $d$ is an infinitesimal, $f'(x)$ can be evaluated without using the limit. Seems like without using the limit notation, it leads to a mistake. I am sorry.

Comment: @DarkKnight I'd say the limit notation is fun for as long as you don't actually have to use its definition. Epsilontik isn't really fun. Well, for differentiation, nonstandard-analysis and analysis coincidence mostly (at least I haven't found any great advantages over standard approaches yet). So, whether you use a limit, or use an infinitesimal, your actual calculation will most likely be analogue (i.e., if you can deduce $\approx$, the same calculation most likely can be used to solve the limit)

Comment: Why is $\lim_{x\to b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \approx\frac{f(b+d+d_2)}{g(b+d+d_2)}$?

Comment: @MikhailKatz Because $$\lim_{x\to b} f(x) \approx f(b+d)$$ and $$ d\approx d + d_2$$. So in other words, it's still infinitesimally close to $x$, just now in another representation. That $$\lim_{x\to b} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \approx\frac{f(b+d+d_2)}{g(b+d+d_2)}$$ then follows, as we assume the limit to exist

Comment: The rule you stated is correct under the assumption that the denominator is appreciable (not infinitesimal).  But here the denominator is infinitesimal so the rule is not applicable.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I see your point... we only want to assume that $\lim_{x\to b} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $ exists. So, let's assume it exists (in a standard sense), and let both $f(x), g(x)$ tend to $0$, as $x\to b$. Then we can deduce: $$\lim_{x\to b} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} \approx\frac{f'(b+d)}{g'(b+d)} =\frac{f(b+d) - f(b) -d_2d_f}{g(b+d) - g(b) -d_2d_g} = \frac{f(b+d)  -d_2d_f}{g(b+d)  -d_2d_g}$$ (We can say $f(b), g(b)$ are defined if we use the analytic continuations of $f,g$ as $f,g$.)

Comment: The trouble is, you are now using the Taylor formula at a nonstandard point $b+d$.  Apriori this formula is known only at a standard point $b$.

Comment: @MikhailKatz And at any rate, this doesn't seem to get me any closer to the solution... It really feels unnerving that this proof, that should definitely be doable in Nonstandard-Analysis, is so tricky. (Yes, of cause, standard reasoning is legitimate in nonstandard-analysis, but this feels more like: If I doesn't work in Nonstandard-analysis, am I really certain the standard proof is correct?)

Comment: The case of L'Hopital is proved in Keisler's book on page 243 is when the limit is $f'(c)/g'(c)$ but the general case is probably treated in the accompanying "foundations" book. I didn't check though.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Thanks for finding this! It seems that the mean-value-theorem is key to obtain this result, no matter the approach. This makes this theorem kinda unique - being a very basic result, yet having no alternative proofs